# Forming Querys based on other Queries?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

I have tables setup like this:

Users Table:

```
ID | Username | Password
1  |   Humza  |   123
3  |   God    |   145
```

Questions Table:

```
Question_ID| Question_Title   | Question      | Rating | Category ID | User ID |
    1      | Testing Display  | Did it Work   |  55    |      2      |    3    |
    2      | Foo is love?     | Same as Above | -100   |      2      |    1    |
    3      | Bla              | Baa Black XD  | 909    |      2      |    1    |
```

Answer Table:

```
Answer_ID| Answer   | Answer_Rating     | Answer_User_ID    | Question_ID |
 1       | YES      |       909         |     1             |      2      | 
 2       | Wohoo    |        15         |     3             |      2      |
```

Reputation Table:

```
Reputation_ID| Reputation | User_Rep_ID|
 1           |   -50      |     1      |
 2           |   9999     |     3      |
```

Category Table:

```
Category_ID  |    Category      | 
 1           |   Dr Who         |    
 2           |  Programming     |  
 3           |   Music          |
```

My Existing query to pick out questions from category 2:

```
SELECT u.username, r.Reputation, q.Question_Title,
q.Question, q.Rating, c.Category, count(a.Answer_ID) as num_answers

FROM Questions q 
INNER JOIN Users u ON u.id = q.User_ID
INNER JOIN Reputation r on r.User_Rep_ID = u.id
INNER JOIN Categorys c ON c.Category_ID = q.Category_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Answers a on q.Question_ID = a.Question_ID
WHERE q.Category_ID = 2
GROUP BY a.Question_ID
```

However for some reason this won't pick out the third question, so it's not perfect.

Current Query to pick out Answers:

```
SELECT u.username as AnswerUserName,
a.Answer, a.Answer_Rating, r.Reputation as AnswerReputation

FROM Answers a
INNER JOIN Users u ON u.ID = a.Answer_User_ID
INNER JOIN Questions q on q.Question_ID = a.Question_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Reputation r ON r.User_Rep_ID = u.ID

WHERE a.Question_ID = q.Question_ID
```

However this seems to just pick out both answers regardless of if the question has an answer or not. thus when I query for all questions in category 1 the same answers will display and im not sure why.

Now I will try and explain to the best of my ability:

1) I need 3 Separate query's which will pick me all questions in category 1, 2 and 3 as well as the users who posted them and their reputation. In addition to this it must also count the number of answers to each question in each category. **Edit - Done**

2) I need a second query which will get me all the answers to the questions which have answers in each category, the username of the person who answered the question and their reputation.

How would I achieve this? If you need more details please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this works at all, actually.  You have non-aggregate fields in your initial query that are not in the GROUP BY statement.  Also, since you know that not every question will have an answer, I'd not group by A.Question_ID - group by q.question_Id instead.  Try this:

```
SELECT u.username, r.Reputation, q.Question_Title,
q.Question, q.Rating, c.Category, count(a.Answer_ID) as num_answers
FROM Questions q 
INNER JOIN Users u ON u.id = q.User_ID
INNER JOIN Reputation r on r.User_Rep_ID = u.id
INNER JOIN Categorys c ON c.Category_ID = q.Category_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Answers a on q.Question_ID = a.Question_ID
WHERE q.Category_ID = 2
GROUP BY u.username, r.Reputation, q.Question_Title,
q.Question, q.Rating, c.Category
```

Comment: I've heard that more than once about how my query actually works lol, it doesn't help when it works but its wrong cause then I can't see the problem EDIT: Thanks This solved 1 of my many problems =)